# Auto Resize a CommandButton based on string length

Tags: excel, vba

I have several commands buttons with text whose captions change based on various inputs. Also want to mention that these are command buttons on the worksheet itself, not on a form.

Is there a way to Auto Resize so that the button width accommodates the length of the text?

Here's a snippet of the pertinent code:

```
Sub FixButtonWidth()
    'Create Button
    Set rbtn = ActiveSheet.Buttons.Add(0, 0, 30, 20)
    'User enters a string of some length
    ShowThis = InputBox("What do you want to call your button?", "Button Name", "")
    'Button Caption changes to whatever the user input
    rbtn.Caption = ShowThis
    'This next line is the problem:
    'The width needs to be based on the width of the string
    'Len(ShowThis) only gives the number of characters in the string . . .
    'Since letters like 'Z' are much wider than letters ...
    'like i (for example), Len(ShowThis) is not a good solution.
    rbtn.Width = 500
End Sub
```

Comment: Check for AutoSize and WordWrap properties

Answer (score 1):

Like I said use `rbtn.AutoSize = True` after the `set rbtn`... part. And remove `rbtn.width = 600`

```
Sub FixButtonWidth()
    'Create Button
    Set rbtn = ActiveSheet.Buttons.Add(0, 0, 30, 20)
    'User enters a string of some length
    ShowThis = InputBox("What do you want to call your button?", "Button Name", "")
    rbtn.AutoSize = True
    'Button Caption changes to whatever the user input
    rbtn.Caption = ShowThis
    'This next line is the problem:
    'The width needs to be based on the width of the string
    'Len(ShowThis) only gives the number of characters in the string . . .
    'Since letters like 'Z' are much wider than letters like i, for example Len(ShowThis) is not the solution
    'rbtn.Width = 500
End Sub
```

Comment: This works beautifully! Much appreciated.